# Documenting field names that Network Dataset Wizard looks for to create network attributes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.4

Is there a definitive list of the field names that the Network Dataset Wizard looks for when it runs, and creates network attributes from?

For example, the Network Dataset Properties below resulted from taking all the defaults on the way through and seems to have automatically created three network attributes:

1. Length - from the Shape field
2. Minutes - because it found a Minutes field
3. Oneway - because it found a One_Way field

[image]

I would have expected these "special" field names to be fully documented at, or on a page linked from, the [Creating a network dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/creating-a-network-dataset.htm) page, but they appear to only be done to this level:

> - Be sure your sources have fields that represent your network impedance values—distance, travel time, and so on. For best results,
>     name these fields as the units of your impedances, since these fields
>     will automatically be detected by the New Network Dataset wizard—for
>     example, you might want to name your travel time field Minutes. For
>     edge sources, if the impedance values differ based on direction of
>     travel, provide a separate field for each direction of travel, for
>     example, FT_Minutes and TF_Minutes.
> - If you are modeling one-way streets, be sure that your edge sources have a field specifying one-way street information. The New Network
>     Dataset wizard recognizes a string field named One_Way or Oneway,
>     creating evaluators that interpret its values as follows:
>
>   - FT or F indicates a one-way street permitting travel only in the digitized direction of the edge.
>   - TF or T indicates a one-way street permitting travel only against the digitized direction of the edge.
>   - N indicates a street that does not permit travel in either direction.
>   - Any other value indicates a street that permits travel in either direction.